# Force click is not working for look up and data detectors on a 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a similar issue documented in [this order question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179721/force-click-not-working-on-macbook) but none of the resolutions mentioned in the discussion solves my case.

Here are my findings so far:

1. It only worked on the first day.
2. I have "Force click with one finger" set for "Look up & data detectors". It still doesn't work. I switched to "Tap with three fingers" and the look up works fine.
3. I tried force click on other functions (eg: calendar, quicktime, dock, etc) all are working fine. This indicates that hardware is good.
4. I upgraded OS X to 10.10.3 and it still does not work.

I am totally stuck now and appreciate for any suggestion on what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I had the same problem with the same conditions except that I'm on macOS Monterey.

I disabled the "Look up & data detectors" check box, logged out of the account and into another user account to see if it was working there. I found the force click lookup to be working!

Then I did a restart into the main account, re-enabled the checkbox and got it to work again.

Sadly, I still have no idea what was wrong but wanted to share.