# How to enable Force Click on Catalina

Tags: trackpad

I like the force click feature to look up the definition of a word but I can't enable it on my system. [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352#:%7E:text=The%20Force%20Touch%20trackpad%20lets,Apple%20menu%20%EF%A3%BF%20%3E%20System%20Preferences.) and the [Force Click Not Working on Macbook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179721/force-click-not-working-on-macbook) post say the Force Click feature should be enabled through the dropdown menu from:

System Preferences > Trackpad > Look up data & detectors > Force Click with one finger dropdown menu

On my macOS Catalina system the force click drop down menu isn't there. How do I add it back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you enable "Force Click and haptic feedback" in your first screenshot (bottom left)?

Comment: It was right under my nose!

Answer (score 1):

Like @Redarm mentions in the comments use the Force Click and haptic feedback setting and then the Force Click with one finger setting becomes available as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]